# HostPath with minikube - Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, docker-volume

UPDATE:
I connected to the minikubevm and I see my host directory mounted but there is no files there. Also when I create a file there it will not in my host machine. Any link are between them

I try to mount an host directory for developing my app with kubernetes.

As the doc recommended, I am using minikube for running my kubernetes cluster on my pc. The goal is to create a develop environment with docker and kubernetes for develop my app. I want to mount a local directory so my docker will read the code app from there. But it is not work. Any help would be really appreciate.

my test app (server.js):

```
var http = require('http');
var handleRequest = function(request, response) {
response.writeHead(200);
response.end("Hello World!");
}
var www = http.createServer(handleRequest);
www.listen(8080);
```

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /code
ADD code/ /code
EXPOSE 8080
CMD server.js
```

my pod kubernetes configuration: (pod-configuration.yaml)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: apiserver
spec:
  containers:
  - name: node
    image: myusername/nodetest:v1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
    volumeMounts:
    - name: api-server-code-files
      mountPath: /code
  volumes:
  - name: api-server-code-files
    hostPath:
      path: /home/<myuser>/Projects/nodetest/api-server/code
```

my folder are:

```
/home/<myuser>/Projects/nodetest/
- pod-configuration.yaml
- api-server/
    - Dockerfile
    - code/
        - server.js
```

When I running my docker image without the hostPath volume it is of course works but the problem is that on each change I will must recreate my image that is really not powerful for development, that's why I need the volume hostPath.

Any idea ? why i don't success to mount my local directory ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDIT: Looks like the solution is to either use a [privilaged container](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/#privileged-mode-for-pod-containers), or to manually mount your home folder to allow the MiniKube VM to read from your hostPath -- https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#virtualbox-guest-additions. (Credit to Eliel for figuring this out).

It is absolutely possible to configure a hostPath volume with minikube - but there are a lot of quirks and there isn't very good support for this particular issue.

Try removing `ADD code/ /code` from your Dockerfile. [Docker's "ADD" instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/add) is copying the code from your host machine into your container's `/code` directory. This is why rebuilding the image successfully updates your code.

When Kubernetes tries to mount the container's `/code` directory to the host path, it finds that this directory is already full of the code that was baked into the image. If you take this out of the build step, Kubernetes should be able to successfully mount the host path at runtime.

Also be sure to check the permissions of the `code/` directory on your host machine.

My only other thought is related to mounting in the root directory. I had issues when mounting Kubernetes hostPath volumes to/from directories in the root directory (I assume this was permissions related). So, something else to try would be a mountPath like `/var/www/html`.

Here's an example of a functional hostPath volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: example-volume
      hostPath:
        path: '/Users/example-user/code'
  containers:
    - name: example-container
      image: example-image
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: '/var/www/html'
          name: example-volume
```

Comment: I update my pod.yaml as you suggest with the mountPath to /var/www/html
but it still doesn't work. What that is weird, that in the previous example when I trying to mount to /code when I connect to minikube via ssh I see in the home directory of the VM the path mounted (/home/<myuser>/Projects/nodetest/api-server/code) but without the server.js file - a priori that's say that is not a issue of permission

Comment: I see that your are running on Mac OS. my host is an ubuntu 16.04. Is it can be related ?

Comment: There are definitely some differences between MacOS and Ubuntu, but it shouldn't change the configuration here. It's interesting to see that it's mounting correctly, but failing to share the actual files. I remember struggling with hostPaths on minikube, but that example I gave was my working solution. So to confirm - if you run `kubectl exec -it apiserver -- ls <mountPath>` it's an empty directory?

Comment: The status of the apiserver node is CrashLoopBackOff since the node throw an exception since it doesn't see the server.js and then the command `kubectl exec -it apiserver -- ls <mountPath>` says me `error: error executing remote command: error executing command in container: container not found ("node")` but when I do `minikube ssh` I see the <mountpath> but without any files..

Comment: For testing purposes, can you edit the command in your docker file to `CMD ["sleep", "1000"]` so that it won't crash on startup?

Comment: Ok we are going forward, when I run `kubectl exec -it apiserver -- ls <mountpath>` I try it with /code and with /var/www/html in both case it show me an empty directory. but It correct mount the path... it is pretty weird

Comment: An another interesting thing it is that when I run `touch server.js` in **minikube** hostPath it say me permission denied... (I think the problem is here) I wanted to know if i put manually the server.js there it will be in my pod when I create it

Comment: What if you run `kubectl exec -it apiserver -- bash` to open up a shell session in the pod and try to create it there? This definitely feels like a permissions issue.

Comment: Ok ! when I change the permision of hostPath in minikube to docker:staff and I add manually the server.js it is works ! BUT the problem that is not linked to my host server.js..

Comment: The only problem now is how to link it to my hostPath

Comment: There is a sentence in the hostPath doc about root privilege but I can understand how it can resolve the problem:

> the directories created on the underlying hosts are only writable by root, you either need to run your process as root in a priveleged container or modify the file permissions on the host to be able to write to a hostPath volume

Comment: So I found the solution, you must manually mount your home folder so the minikube VM will be able to read from your hostPath, as the boot2docker doc says: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#virtualbox-guest-additions
Your response and comments was the most helpful, so edit your response with the solution and I'll approve it (and you'll gain the bounty :))

Comment: Awesome job figuring this out, and thanks for sharing the solution! I edited the response above, and hopefully it will help others going forwards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118959/discussion-between-eliel-haouzi-and-springle).

Comment: Hi Eliel Haouzi, this discussion was very helpful, do you know the way to make the hostPath relative? Docs says that it's impossible at the moment but maybe there is some hacks for this?

Answer (score 11):

They have now given the `minikube mount` which works on all environment

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/host_folder_mount.md

Tried on Mac:

```
$ minikube mount ~/stuff/out:/mnt1/out
Mounting /Users/macuser/stuff/out into /mnt1/out on the minikube VM
This daemon process needs to stay alive for the mount to still be accessible...
ufs starting
```

And in pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myServer
spec:
  containers:
  - name: myServer
    image: myImage
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /mnt1/out
      name: volume
    # Just spin & wait forever
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]
  volumes:
  - name: volume
    hostPath:
      path: /mnt1/out
```

Answer (score -4):

Best practice would be building the code into your image, you should not run an image with code just coming from the disk. Your Dockerfile should look more like:

`FROM node:latest
COPY /code/server.js /code/server.js
EXPOSE 8080
CMD /code/server.js`

Then you run the Image on Kubernetes without any volumes. You need to rebuild the image and update the pod every time you update the code.

Also, I'm currently not aware that minikube allows for mounts between the VM it creates and the host you are running it on.

If you really want the extreme fast feedback cycle of changing code while the container is running, you might be able to use just Docker by itself with `-v /path/to/host/code:/code` without Kubernetes and then once you are ready build the image and deploy and test it on minikube. However, I'm not sure that would work if you're changing the main .js file of your node app.

Comment: Thank for your response. The advantage of running Kubernetes locally is your dev environment is like your prod env. 
mount local directories to pods will improve the developer experience a lot.
If as an example my project need a redis instance I want to run it also in my dev env with kubernetes to check that they are well linked.
I am searching a way to mount a hostPath from minikube Vm to my host.
This minikube issue says that it possible https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2
but i don't know how.

Comment: Sure, I do understand your need to have dev prod parity. Still, the issue you mention is open and not solved, yet. The only way is to mount NFS from your host into the VM like described in the issue here: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2#issuecomment-233629375

Comment: My question still stays, AFAIK there's no hot swapping of code in node.js so you would need to restart anyway. Why would you not build the code into your image?

Comment: You are right about the nodejs server, it need manually restart when the code is updated, but that was only for the example, my real app is a python one that do auto-reload when the code is changed. My goal was to run the same env in the dev and prod env. Nevertheless thanks for your trying to find a solution.

Comment: Ok, with python and auto-reload I can understand the use case. Btw, there's a nice vagrant setup that mounts NFS from the host and is multi-node. This might be nicer for having dev prod parity for you: https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-vagrant-coreos-cluster