# Is there any way to share a Kubernetes volume between a Minikube directory and a local Windows 10 directory?

Tags: windows, docker, kubernetes, minikube, docker-volume

What I want to achieve is similar to a volume shared between a pod's container and a local Minikube directory but with Minikube and Windows 10 directories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HostPath with minikube - Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682114/hostpath-with-minikube-kubernetes)

Comment: What kind of hypervisor do you use for `Minikube` (VirtualBox, Hyper-V)?

Comment: I use VirtualBox.